# Limiting column header width in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, psql

When doing a select on a table in my postgres database, the column headers are way too wide. Psql allocates as much space for the column header as the maximum size of each column, which is unnecessary and makes it wrap, making output harder to read:

`sams=# select * from products;
  prod_id   |  vend_id   |                                                                                                                            prod_name                                                                                                                            | prod_price |                               prod_desc

------------+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
 BR01       | BRS01      | 8 inch teddy bear                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |       5.99 | 8 inch teddy bear, comes with cap and jacket
 BR02       | BRS01      | 12 inch teddy bear               :`

I have tried to set the environment variable COLUMNS to another value, say 20, but that doesn't change anything. Changing the width of the column is not the solution - I want to have a large width in case, but since most values will be far shorter, I want it only to use the maximum required width for the current data.

Comment: You can use `\a` to set unaligned output mode. I find `\x` view mode useful too.

Comment: "*Psql allocates as much space for the column header as the maximum size of each column*" - for me it always allocates as much space as data is *stored* in the column. Can you show us the _definition_ of your table?

Comment: \a is definately useful, and \x in some cases (but not for compact viewing of tables). The definition of the table is as follows:`code`sams=# \d products;
 prod_id    | character(10)           | not null
 vend_id    | character(10)           | not null
 prod_name  | character(255)          | not null
 prod_price | numeric(8,2)            | not null
 prod_desc  | character varying(1000) |